# text align justify not working on element generated by add_shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress, css

This is the weirdest problem I have ever encounter in my whole life, I've been debugging it for almost 5 hours as I have a very long code until I got to this and realize that the reason its not working is because of how the HTML code was generated.

Just check this page, http://sites.symmetricsweb.com/

First box HTML code is the same with the second box,

However, text align justify is not working on the second box,

The first box html code is added using page editor

```
<div class="checs"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

while the second box is generated using add_shortcode functionality,

```
add_shortcode('test_short','my_function');
function my_function() {
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="checs"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

but If you examine the HTML source, you won't see any difference,

I don't really need a solution to this as there are many ways I know to separate the boxes evenly, I just wanted to know what is the reason why `text-align:justify` is behaving this way.

Would appreciate any good explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated HTML **isn't** identical to the first set of divs.

From the page source - first set:

```
<div><strong>Added Directly on Page Editor</strong></div>
<div class="checs">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

And the second set -

```
<div><strong>Generated using add_shortcode()</strong></div>
<div class="checs"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

The CSS as written needs the whitespace of the carriage returns to space the divs out properly.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6rrbru0/)**

Comment: Thanks, I should have listen all the details during HTML class, lol not aware that white space would affect CSS behavior